# Join every two lines after the expression in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, text, sed

I have the following text file that contains:

```
Environment: MS001
GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST
EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2
EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T
EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01
GATEWAY TEST: S_C
EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```

I would like to obtain this result

```
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01,GATEWAY TEST: S_C,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```

Basically group each gw by environment, I'm trying this but I can't get it

`awk -F: '/^Environment/{ITM=$0} !/^Environment/{print ITM"=>"$0}'`

Comment: Don't the string `"=>"` since that string doesn't exist in your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two lines after "Environment" always contain the same terms (i.e. GATEWAY TEST and EXECUTION-RESULT) you could use:

```
awk '/Environment/ {e = $0} /GATEWAY TEST/ {gt = $0} /EXECUTION-RESULT/ {print e "," gt "," $0}' file
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01,GATEWAY TEST: S_C,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```

Comment: It's what I was looking for, it hadn't occurred to me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This stores the line in a variable if it starts with `Environment`. Otherwise it prints the last stored line, and the current two lines, separated by commas:

```bash
awk '/^Environment/ {h=$0; next} {a=$0; getline; print h "," a "," $0}'
```

```
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01,GATEWAY TEST: S_C,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```

Tested with mawk 1.3.4, nawk 20231228, and GNU Awk 5.3.0

Comment: You could've done `getline a; print h "," $0 "," a` to save a couple of chars (the initial `a=$0;`). You'll get interesting results with any unprotected `getline` approach if the file isn't complete, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline, but the OP didn't tell us how to handle that case anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for something like this:

```
$ awk '/^Environment/{gw=env=$0; next} {gw=gw","$0} ++c==2{print gw; gw=env; c=0}' file
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01,GATEWAY TEST: S_C,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^Environment/{h;d};N;s/\n/,/;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2,\1/' input_file
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01,GATEWAY TEST: S_C,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```

Comment: Or perhaps `sed -E '/^Environment/{h;d};N;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\3,\1,\2/' file`

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '
    /^Environment/ { env=$0; n=0; next }
    (++n)%2 { pre=$0; next }
    { print env, pre, $0 }
' file
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01,GATEWAY TEST: S_C,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```

or, IMO simpler and clearer but more tightly coupled to the data values, also using any awk:

```
$ awk -F':' -v OFS=',' '
    { a[$1] = $0 }
    $1 == "EXECUTION-RESULT" {
        print a["Environment"], a["GATEWAY TEST"], $0
    }
' file
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01,GATEWAY TEST: S_C,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '
    /Environment/{ttl = $0; next}
    /GATEWAY/{subttl = $0; next}
    {print ttl, subttl, $0}
' file
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_ST,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CV_T2,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MS001,GATEWAY TEST: CVI_T,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
Environment: MT01,GATEWAY TEST: S_C,EXECUTION-RESULT: 0
```